# include файла по значению selected option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Как переделать код так чтобы при выборе года в селекторе инклюдился (или другим способом загружался) код из файла с выбранным годом (с загруженным кодом работают скрипты).

```
    <select class="form-select m-3 mb-0 text-center" id="year_selector" style="width: calc(100% - 2rem);">
        <option value="2020"<?php if (date('Y') == 2020) {echo ' selected';} else {echo '';}; ?> >2020</option>
        <option value="2021"<?php if (date('Y') == 2021) {echo ' selected';} else {echo '';}; ?> >2021</option>
        <option value="2022"<?php if (date('Y') == 2022) {echo ' selected';} else {echo '';}; ?> >2022</option>
        <option value="2023"<?php if (date('Y') == 2023) {echo ' selected';} else {echo '';}; ?> >2023</option>
        <option value="2024"<?php if (date('Y') == 2024) {echo ' selected';} else {echo '';}; ?> >2024</option>
    </select>

    <?php
    include '2022.php';
    ?>
```

Подойдут как PHP так и JS и jQuery (3.5.1) решения. Хотя я сомневаюсь что на php такое вообще возможно, но если вдруг возможно, то предпочтительнее php, все таки сервер быстрее телефона, пускай он вычисляет.

Comment: для такого существуют GET/POST запросы, ajax/xhr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$dateList = [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024];
$currentDate = (isset($_POST['year_selector']) and in_array($_POST['year_selector'], $dateList)) ? $_POST['year_selector'] : date('Y');



echo '<form method="POST"><select class="form-select m-3 mb-0 text-center" id="year_selector" name="year_selector" style="width: calc(100% - 2rem);">';
foreach ($dateList as $date) {
  echo '<option value="'.$date.'" '.($currentDate == $date ? " selected" : "").'>'.$date.'</option>';
}
echo '</select></form>';

include $currentDate.'php';
?>
```

Можно и на php, решение правда не лучшее... вам останется повесить обработчик отправки формы (кнопку или onchange по селекту)

Comment: Где-то здесь есть ошибка: '.($currentDate == $date ? " selected" : ""

Comment: Да, действительно, забыл закрыть скобку)
`echo '<option value="'.$date.'" '.($currentDate == $date ? " selected" : "").'>'.$date.'</option>';`
Писал прямо тут, синтаксис не подсвечивало( в VScode, например, такого бы не случилось